# How to programmatically subscribe an async consumer to a queue in Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

Spring AMQP documentation only shows how to programmatically subscribe to a queue at application initialization time using a `~MessageListenerContainer`.

The code now looks as follows:

```
public void subscribe(EventType eventType, Object consumer) {
        Assert.notNull(eventType);
        Assert.notNull(eventType.toString());
        Assert.isTrue(!eventType.toString().isEmpty());

        Queue queue=new Queue("", false, true, true);
        Map<String, Exchange> beanMap=context.getBeansOfType(Exchange.class);
        if(beanMap!=null&&!beanMap.isEmpty()){
            Exchange exchange=null;
            boolean found=false;
            for(String key : beanMap.keySet()) {
                exchange=beanMap.get(key);
                if(getExchangeName(eventType.toString()).equals(exchange.getName())){
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found){
                amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
                amqpAdmin.declareBinding(new Binding(queue.getName(), Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchange.getName(), "", null));
                SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
                container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                container.setQueueNames(queue.getName());
                container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(consumer));
            }else{
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }
```

As the SimpleMessageListenerContainer is a lifecycle bean, it won't work unless used in a `@Configuration` bean

I need to programmatically create subscriptions at run time so a bean gets events from a queue. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just an advance warning from experience.. The `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` is very heavy beast of an Object. You do not want to go around creating 1000's of these objects. Its better to make a couple that take a ton of queues or do some other type of dispatching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gary Russells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) response is right but my code still had some remaining errors:

- If you create the Queue with no name, RabbitMQ <strike>creates</strike> gives it a random unique name. You have to retrieve it the moment you declare the queue and then use this name when declaring the container and the binding

For clarity I add the modified code block in its final version:

```
    public void subscribe(EventType eventType, AbstractEventConsumer consumer) {
    Assert.notNull(eventType);
    Assert.notNull(eventType.toString());
    Assert.isTrue(!eventType.toString().isEmpty());

    Queue queue=new Queue("", false, true, true);
    Map<String, Exchange> beanMap=context.getBeansOfType(Exchange.class);
    if(beanMap!=null&&!beanMap.isEmpty()){
        Exchange exchange=null;
        boolean found=false;
        for(String key : beanMap.keySet()) {
            exchange=beanMap.get(key);
            if(getExchangeName(eventType.toString()).equals(exchange.getName())){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            String queueName=amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            amqpAdmin.declareBinding(new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchange.getName(), "", null));
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(queueName);
            container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(consumer));
            container.start();
        }else{
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your question is. You can create the container at runtime; just invoke `start()` after you configure it. There are many test cases that do exactly this.

You can also add queues to an existing container (and remove them); the container's consumers will be recycled to start consuming from new queue list.

Comment: Thanks Gary, you put me in the right track. I 've completed your answer with some further clarification and final code.